# How to bind var's name and value in the clojure macro?

Tags: variables, clojure, macros, lisp

Assum I hava some(more than 20) variables, I want to save them to a file. I don't want to repeat 20 times the same code.
I wrote a macro but it gave me an error.

my test case:

```
;-----------------------------------------------
(defn processor [ some-parameters ]

  (let [
  ;after some operation ,got these data:
        date-str ["JN01","JN02","JN03","JN04"];length 8760
        date-temperature (map #(str %2 "," %1) [3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6] date-str) ; all vector's length are 8760
        date-ws (map #(str %2 "," %1) [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4] date-str)          ; 
        ;... many variables such like date-relative-humidity,date-pressure, name starts with "date-",
        ; all same size
        ]
    ;(doseq [e date-temperature]
    ;  (println e))
    (spit "output-variable_a.TXT"
          (with-out-str
            (doseq [e date-temperature]
              (println e))))
    ;same 'spit' part will repeat many times
    ))

(processor 123)
; I NEED to output other variables(ws, wd, relative-humidity, ...)
; Output example:
;JN01,3.3
;JN02,4.4
;JN03,5.5
;JN04,6.6
;-----------------------------------------------
```

what I want is a macro/function I can use this way:

```
(write-to-text temperature,ws,wd,pressure,theta-in-k,mixradio)
```

and this macro/function will do the work.
I don't know how to write such a macro/function.

My macro post here but it doesn't work:

```
(defmacro write-array [& rest-variables ]
  `(doseq [ vname# '~rest-variables ]
     ;(println vname# vvalue#)
     (println "the vname# is" (symbol vname#))
     (println "resolve:" (resolve (symbol (str vname# "-lines"))))
     (println "resolve2:" (resolve (symbol (str "ws-lines"))))
     (let [ vvalue# 5] ;(var-get (resolve (symbol vname#)))]
       ;----------NOTE:  commented out cause '(symbol vname#)' won't work.
       ;1(spit (str "OUT-" vname# ".TXT" )
       ;1      (with-out-str
       ;1        (doseq [ l (var-get (resolve (symbol (str vname# "-lines"))))]
       ;1          (println l))))

       (println vname# vvalue#))))
```

I found that the problem is `(symbol vname#)` part, this method only works for a **GLOBAL** variable, cannot bound to date-temperature **in** the **LET** form,`(symbol vname#)` returns nil.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to write a file of delimited values using binding names and their values from inside a `let`. Macros transform code during compilation and so they cannot know the run-time *values* that the symbols you pass are bound to. You can use a macro to emit code that will be evaluated at run-time:

```clj
(defmacro to-rows [& args]
  (let [names (mapv name args)]
    `(cons ~names (map vector ~@args))))    

(defn get-stuff []
  (let [nums [1 2 3]
        chars [\a \b \c]
        bools [true false nil]]
    (to-rows nums chars bools)))

(get-stuff)
=> (["nums" "chars" "bools"]
    [1 \a true]
    [2 \b false]
    [3 \c nil])
```

Alternatively you could produce a hash map per row:

```clj
(defmacro to-rows [& args]
  (let [names (mapv name args)]
    `(map (fn [& vs#] (zipmap ~names vs#)) ~@args)))

=> ({"nums" 1, "chars" \a, "bools" true}
    {"nums" 2, "chars" \b, "bools" false}
    {"nums" 3, "chars" \c, "bools" nil})
```

You would then need to write that out to a file, either using data.csv or similar code.

To see what `to-rows` expands to, you can use `macroexpand`. This is the code being *generated* at compile-time that will be *evaluated* at run-time. It does the work of getting the symbol *names* at compile-time, but emits code that will work on their bound *values* at run-time.

```clj
(macroexpand '(to-rows x y z))
=> (clojure.core/cons ["x" "y" "z"] (clojure.core/map clojure.core/vector x y z))
```

As an aside, I'm assuming you aren't typing thousands of literal values into `let` bindings. I think this answers the question as asked but there could likely be a more direct approach than this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out the method of geting both var's name and var's value,  the 'to-rows' macro, Yes I do want to write them to a file seperated by ',' . Let me have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the function `name`.  To demonstrate:

```clj
user=> (defmacro write-columns [& columns]
         (let [names (map name columns)]
           `(str ~@names)))
#'user/write-columns
user=> (write-columns a b c)
"abc"
```

Comment: I think their problem is more with figuring out what's happening at macro-time vs runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can first capture the variable names and their values into a map:

```
(defmacro name-map
  [& xs]
  (let [args-list# (cons 'list (map (juxt (comp keyword str) identity) xs))]
    `(into {} ~args-list#)))
```

If you pass the var names to the macro,

```
(let [aa 11
      bb 22
      cc 33]
   (name-map aa bb cc))
```

It gives you a map which you can then use for any further processing:

```
=> {:aa 11, :bb 22, :cc 33}
(def result *1)
(run! 
  (fn [[k v]] (println (str "spit file_" (name k) " value: " v)))
  result)
=>
spit file_aa value: 11
spit file_bb value: 22
spit file_cc value: 33
```

Edit: Just noticed it's similar to Taylor's macro. The difference is this one works with primitive types as well, while Taylor's works for the original data (vars resolving to collections).